# Is there any way to hide an Image(cardview) from users that are not speaking frensh

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I think the title says everything. On my homescreen I have 6 categories (images). 5 of them Can be seen by everyone. (android studio)
What I want to do is hide the last categorie from non frensh speaking users, if this is possible.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes the main screen of my application. I am Using Strings on the value section.

Comment: I am not using any web service. just an app on android studio. a simple one. no webview is used.

Comment: include the image only in the `"frensh"` drawable folder. So, the `"englich"` speaking users won't see it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you check if the current language is French.

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fr")
```

So if, for example, you want to hide a certain view for French users, you could use

```
boolean french = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fr")
view.visibility = french ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
```

or something similar. This is assuming, of course, that you did not call `Locale.setDefault` at any point beforehand.

Comment: Even simpler than coding: include the image only in the `"frensh"` drawable folder. So, only the `"frensh"` speaking users will see it.

Comment: @Fantômas that works if you want a _different_ drawable for French users. However, the OP wants _no_ drawable for French users, you can't do that with resources.

Comment: No, he wants a drawable for "frensh" users and NO drawable for the other ones. So, simply put the drawable ONLY in that "frensh" folder and NOTHING in the other drawable folders. DONE.

Comment: @Fantômas you can't put a drawable only in the "french" drawable folder. There has to be one in the default drawable folder too.

Comment: Good catch. Then, you can put a 1x1 pixel (with full transparency) in the default folder.